# "error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector"and I'm using a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm writing a program for zoj 1733, and the problem is on line 8:

```
else if(x[i] == y[j])return f(i-1,j-1)+1;
```

Why I can't use "x[i]" while x is a string? And I don't understand the tip"subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector". The follow is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string x,y;
int f(int i,int j){
    int x,y;
    if(i==0 || j==0)return 0;                       
    else if(x[i] == y[j])return f(i-1,j-1)+1;
    else {
        x=f(i-1,j);
        y=f(i,j-1);
        if(x>y)return x;
        else return y;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i,j;
    while(cin>>x>>y){
        i=x.size();j=y.size();
        cout<<f(i,j)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare `x` and `y` as string global variables, and also as integer local variables. When you access them inside the function, it'll consider the integer version as they're in closer scope. Change the name of either of them and it should work fine.

Edit: By "either of them" I mean change the names of the global variables or the local variables, not either x or y :)

You can also reference the global variables inside the function by using `::x` and `::y`. This will inform the compiler to access the global one, but I'd really suggest to just change the variables names.